# why is sliding drawer in android deprecated in API 17?

Tags: android, navigation, slidingdrawer

I am new to android app development. Using API19 in android studio 1.2. I found sliding drawer attractive to use in my app. But when I used it in design layout, i got to know that it is deprecated. Hint says it is unsupported and use your own implementation.

Why was it deprecated  ?
Can I still use deprecated API without any issues ?
If not, how can i implement feature similar to sliding drawer from UI perspective ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I still use deprecated API

Yes. It still exists.

> without any issues ?

Since Google is no longer maintaining it, it may not work well on future versions of Android.

> how can i implement feature similar to sliding drawer from UI perspective ?

Use any one of the [many sliding panels available as third-party libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/90).

Comment: do you know why it has been deprecated?

Comment: @Blackbelt: Not really. I mean, `SlidingDrawer` was never especially flexible, and it has a very pre-Holo look to it, so it hasn't ever received a lot of love. Really, they had it for the Android 1.x stock home screen launcher. So, out of the widget library, if they were going to deprecate one (e.g., to reduce maintenance costs), I'm not shocked that they picked this one. That being said, I have no idea what their rationale really was.

Comment: Thanks commonsWare for the answers and the link !